# Set UseDatabaseNullSemantics for generated DbContext EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF6 DbContext that is auto generated from a model on to which I would like to set UseDatabaseNullSemantics to true.

I don't want to set UseDatabaseNullSemantics the value on each instance of the DbContext (that would mean to much code) and since it is generated I can't set UseDatabaseNullSemantics the value in the DbContext's constructor.

Is there a way for me to set UseDatabaseNullSemantics to true for the application once and for all?

Edit + Clarification:

My "FordonTrpEntities" DbContext subclass is autogenerated and located in/under the "FordontTrp.edmx" model file.

[image]

If I set the configuration in the constructor of this class won't it be erased if/when the file is regenerated? As stated in the file header:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public partial class FordonTrpEntities : DbContext
{
    public FordonTrpEntities()
        : base("name=FordonTrpEntities")
    {
        Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you are aware of the impact of this setting. It may produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to set it in the constructor of the DbContext class like this:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext 
{
     public YourDbContext() 
     {
          Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
     }

     // DbSet declarations
}
```

You'll notice a huge performance improvement in most of the queries where you have filters as it will not add null checks to the conditions.

If you are working with auto-generated code, you cannot modify this class directly because it will be overriden. In that case you can modify the TT file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've clarified my question a bit. Is your answer still valid? Do you know when the file is/can be regenerated?

Comment: @x3m Do not modify the CS file directly, it will get overwritten. But this answer is correct nonetheless. That same change can and should be made in the TT file.

Comment: @hvd Excellent! I got it working by modifying the TT file as you pointed out. 

Francisco if you modify your answer so that the TT file is mentioned I can approve it! :)

Comment: I added an extra comment for the TT file.